# C# VB2015 Imported Form not referencing in Program

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, import

I'm having some serious issues when attempting to add an existing form from one Project to another. I have done a bit of research regarding how to add existing forms correctly to a project and I have located the file through Add Existing. I have also rebuilt the original project to the correct .Net framework (as it was using 4.00 and my current project is using 4.5.2) the issue i am having is when trying to initiate the new form in a button click in my main menu form it does not show up for instance when attempting to reference the form (new Project.Test.Test) it does not recognise the form as part of the project.

All other solutions i have found don't seem to work for me.

edit : This is the code from from test.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace StackedHeader
{
public partial class Test : Form
    {
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StackedHeaderDecorator objREnderer = new StackedHeaderDecorator(dataGridView1);
            //dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            //dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                int columnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + dataGridView1.Columns.Count,
                                          "Parent[" + columnCount + "].Child 1.Child 2.Input Name");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + dataGridView1.Columns.Count ,
                                          "Parent[" + columnCount + "].Child 1.Child 2.Input Name 2");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + dataGridView1.Columns.Count,
                                          "Parent[" + columnCount + "].Child 1.Child 3.Input Name 3");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + dataGridView1.Columns.Count ,
                                          "Parent[" + columnCount + "].Child 1.Input Name 4");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + dataGridView1.Columns.Count ,
                                          "Parent[" + columnCount + "].Input Name 5");
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my form design code:

```
namespace StackedHeader
{
    partial class Test
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.e = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column5 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column6 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column7 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column8 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column9 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column10 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column11 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column12 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column13 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column14 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column15 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column16 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column17 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column18 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column19 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column20 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column21 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column22 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column23 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column24 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column25 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column26 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column27 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column28 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Column1,
            this.e,
            this.Column3,
            this.Column4,
            this.Column5,
            this.Column2,
            this.Column6,
            this.Column7,
            this.Column8,
            this.Column9,
            this.Column10,
            this.Column11,
            this.Column12,
            this.Column13,
            this.Column14,
            this.Column15,
            this.Column16,
            this.Column17,
            this.Column18,
            this.Column19,
            this.Column20,
            this.Column21,
            this.Column22,
            this.Column23,
            this.Column24,
            this.Column25,
            this.Column26,
            this.Column27,
            this.Column28});
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1492, 697);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
            // 
            // Column1
            // 
            this.Column1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            this.Column1.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Monday.On";
            this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
            this.Column1.Width = 50;
            // 
            // e
            // 
            this.e.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Monday.Off";
            this.e.Name = "e";
            this.e.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column3
            // 
            this.Column3.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Monday.Duty";
            this.Column3.Name = "Column3";
            this.Column3.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column4
            // 
            this.Column4.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Monday.Hours";
            this.Column4.Name = "Column4";
            this.Column4.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column5
            // 
            this.Column5.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Tuesday.On";
            this.Column5.Name = "Column5";
            this.Column5.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column2
            // 
            this.Column2.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Tuesday.Off";
            this.Column2.Name = "Column2";
            this.Column2.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column6
            // 
            this.Column6.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Tuesday.Duty";
            this.Column6.Name = "Column6";
            this.Column6.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column7
            // 
            this.Column7.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Tuesday.Hours";
            this.Column7.Name = "Column7";
            this.Column7.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column8
            // 
            this.Column8.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Wednesday.On";
            this.Column8.Name = "Column8";
            this.Column8.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column9
            // 
            this.Column9.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Wednesday.Off";
            this.Column9.Name = "Column9";
            this.Column9.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column10
            // 
            this.Column10.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Wednesday.Duty";
            this.Column10.Name = "Column10";
            this.Column10.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column11
            // 
            this.Column11.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Wednesday.Hours";
            this.Column11.Name = "Column11";
            this.Column11.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column12
            // 
            this.Column12.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Thursday.On";
            this.Column12.Name = "Column12";
            this.Column12.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column13
            // 
            this.Column13.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Thursday.Off";
            this.Column13.Name = "Column13";
            this.Column13.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column14
            // 
            this.Column14.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Thursday.Duty";
            this.Column14.Name = "Column14";
            this.Column14.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column15
            // 
            this.Column15.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Thursday.Hours";
            this.Column15.Name = "Column15";
            this.Column15.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column16
            // 
            this.Column16.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Friday.On";
            this.Column16.Name = "Column16";
            this.Column16.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column17
            // 
            this.Column17.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Friday.Off";
            this.Column17.Name = "Column17";
            this.Column17.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column18
            // 
            this.Column18.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Friday.Duty";
            this.Column18.Name = "Column18";
            this.Column18.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column19
            // 
            this.Column19.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Friday.Hours";
            this.Column19.Name = "Column19";
            this.Column19.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column20
            // 
            this.Column20.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Saturday.On";
            this.Column20.Name = "Column20";
            this.Column20.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column21
            // 
            this.Column21.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Saturday.Off";
            this.Column21.Name = "Column21";
            this.Column21.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column22
            // 
            this.Column22.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Saturday.Duty";
            this.Column22.Name = "Column22";
            this.Column22.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column23
            // 
            this.Column23.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Saturday.Hours";
            this.Column23.Name = "Column23";
            this.Column23.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column24
            // 
            this.Column24.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Sunday.On";
            this.Column24.Name = "Column24";
            this.Column24.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column25
            // 
            this.Column25.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Sunday.Off";
            this.Column25.Name = "Column25";
            this.Column25.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column26
            // 
            this.Column26.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Sunday.Duty";
            this.Column26.Name = "Column26";
            this.Column26.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column27
            // 
            this.Column27.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Sunday.Hours";
            this.Column27.Name = "Column27";
            this.Column27.Width = 50;
            // 
            // Column28
            // 
            this.Column28.HeaderText = "MasterRoster.Total Hours";
            this.Column28.Name = "Column28";
            this.Column28.Width = 50;
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1510, 46);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 680);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "All",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday"});
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1510, 19);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 21);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1510, 3);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label1.Text = "Duty Day Picker";
            // 
            // Test
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1670, 738);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Test";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn e;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column7;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column8;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column9;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column10;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column11;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column12;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column13;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column14;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column15;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column16;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column17;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column18;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column19;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column20;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column21;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column22;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column23;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column24;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column25;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column26;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column27;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column28;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: Are you trying to add a VB.NET based Windows-Form to a C# Windows Forms Project?

Comment: Bug finder, what code would you like? It simply won't show the form I have imported when attempting to code. As in when I start typing projectname. VB shows my original forms I.e main menu form 1 form 2 Ecr. But the new form "test" does not show in the list, bass fader where do I find that information? Both projects where compiled in VB2015

Comment: Normally when they don't show up in autocomplete, it means that the class is out of scope. Missing refrence etc. Please post the code of the form declaration and the instantiation from your code.

Comment: RIghtlick on the Solution's References -> Add Reference -> Projects -> Set CheckBox on desired project

Comment: Kassi, I have got it to recognise the original through referencing as you described. when calling the form i now get "The type Test conflicts with the origional type 'test'" i believe this is because it is finding the form that i have added to my new project. I would prefer if possible not referencing a different project as i would like to have this form as part of the new project as the original was only for testing purposes.

Comment: ib11: i literally have not added any code yet i am stuck at the first hurdle of getting it recognised by my new project. I am very new at this so if i am missing something let me know. Or if i am being a noob and not understanding what you are asking!

Comment: I have updated my post with all relevant code to the form.